# Irritating window stuck always on top

Tags: unity, gnome, cinnamon

10.
Sometimes there is a small window(corrupt) appearing, once it is there, it sticks there on top of all, irrespctive of whatever I do except logout.

I have tried different options like cinnamon, gnome, unity but changing desktop env doesn't affect.

here are screenshots

https://plus.google.com/photos/117223692780140475095/albums/5855916079499435233/5855916086224463218
https://plus.google.com/photos/117223692780140475095/albums/5855916079499435233/5855916080221541970

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use xkill to stop the process that generated this window. Just open a terminal and run xkill, you will see the mouse pointer changes shape, then click the corrupted window and a kill signal will be sent to the process owning the window. Hopefully the corrupted window will disappear.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I shall try this next time that window appears

Comment: Xkilling doesn't work, becuase though the window is appearing on top, focus/control (of mouse etc) is on the window below, so xkill kills the window below. The ghost window is visible but not clickable. It appears that no action can be done the window.

Comment: I have tried xwininfo, ps etc. It seems there is no process, so it can not be killed. How can I clear the xserver or window managers buffers without affecting other windows or restarting it?

Comment: now it has started stacking up https://plus.google.com/photos/117223692780140475095/albums/5855916079499435233/5856570612632991202?banner=pwa

Answer (score 0):

Right mouse click on Cinnamon's (task)bar -> `Troubleshooting` -> `Restart Cinnamon`.

Must be a Cinnamon bug.

Comment: There is a fix for cinnamon, it is a none bug, and if you modify window manager.js it can be fixed, I'll go hunt for the bug report.

Comment: Right replace /usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/windowManager.js with this code: https://raw.github.com/ebbes/Cinnamon/a945375225d64c1858e2e5540cf5c19c12eff5fc/js/ui/windowManager.js and it is fixed for cinnamon,